# how to use sprite image as stage background and add another sprite image on the stage background

Tags: android, libgdx

i added image to background and want to add some button to the background, on the code below my image background gets disappear

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Button image gets disappear modifying above code

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a stage then you need to create a class for the sprite which extends Actor. And then you need to add the actor to the stage. The stage on the other hand will call the actors batch to draw the sprite. Your code should be something like:

```
public class MyActor extends Actor {
Sprite sprite;

public MyActor () {
    sprite = new Sprite..
    //sprite features
    ...
}


 @Override
public void act(float delta) {
   super.act(delta);
}

@Override
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    sprite.draw(batch);
 }
}
```

And then when you create the stage

```
//this will create your sprite
MyActor actor = new MyActor();
stage.addActor(actor);
```

And in the stage render method leave only:

```
public void render () {
 Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 camera.update();
 stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
 stage.draw(); //this will call the batch to draw the sprite
}
```

For more info check scene2d [docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)

Also, for a complete example please have a look [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-1.aspx)